# Server Error (500) after deploying django app

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-staticfiles

I have to deploy a PyTorch model using Django and I have static files which include images, CSS, and javascript files. After deploying by using `whitenoise` and disabling `COLLECTSTATIC` I am getting server errors after deploying using Heroku. need help.
I have attached my settings.py file code below for reference

```py
from pathlib import Path
import os

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-2e(@-ilm2ph7sx34c-0^!o4bcjt2#fx^j=l(m$ey@aqe823q62'
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['labwebsitetest.herokuapp.com','127.0.0.1:8000']

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'lab.apps.LabConfig',
    
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'website.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'website.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'


DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should migrate apps to databases.

try this:

first step: you should login to heroku in terminal.

```
heroku login
```

and then try this:

```
heroku run python manage.py migrate
```

and you can also DEBUG=True to have Django show errors.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

you can try like;

```
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).